# Rectangles in one dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to prove the following proposition :

Show that the intesection of two rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is either the vaccum or is another rectangle.

My attempt:

I one is embeded in the other we finish, but if not I want to prove it for dimension 1 (where we know that the rectangles are either point or an interval) but if we negate that the intesection is the vaccum then we are done because the thing is that there exists a point $x$ in the intersection that is a rectangle.

Since we have it for $n=1$ than we choose two rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, if we assume that the intesection is not the vaccum then exists a vector $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that every component is in one of the intervals that conform the rectangles, but we can reduce this to dimension 1 because each of the borders (well we call them in class faces because we are in demension n) of the triangles are lines in the space of dimension 1, then we have prove above that when $n=1$ the proposition is true therefore we have that each of the borders intersects in one interval, hence that intervals are the new rectangle that we were aked for.

The question is Am I right?, what do I have to change?,Can you help me to fix those mistakes please?, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Start by providing the exact and rigorous definition of these rectangles.

Comment: which ones in R or in R^n?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: well the definition in R is the one that I gave above isnt and in R^n is only the cartesian product of n intervals, am I right?

Comment: Do you mean a closed interval ?

Comment: well it depends on the rectangle, you can have an open rectangle or a closed one

Comment: "it depends" does not make a rigorous definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let a rectangle be defined by two points $[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as the the set of $x$ such that $a\le x\le b$. (The inequalities must hold for every component.) If for some component $a_i>b_i$, the rectangle is void.

Now the intersection of the rectangles $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ is the set of $x$ such that $a\le x\le b\land c\le x\le d$.

In other words, $(a\max c)\le x\le(b\min d)$ (component-wise maximum and minimum), or

$$[a,b]\cap[c,d]=[a\max c,b\min d].$$

The intersection of two rectangles is a rectangle.

Comment: thanks a lot :) but can you explain the max and min steps please :)

Comment: $a\le x\land c\le x\implies(a\max c)\le x$.

Comment: well I think I dont undestand the notation :) what is a max c

Comment: max(a,c) as a dyadic operator.

Comment: mm we havent seen that :) yet

Comment: Never heard of the largest of two numbers ?

Comment: ooo yes but that name confused me jajajajaja, then with this we are done or do I have to add more things?

Comment: I leave it to you.

Comment: well that is that I have to add more things ? jajajajaja

Comment: thanks a lot @Yves Daoust and I think it is complete I will only add the proof protocol of negating and writting the suppositions and thats all ;) well I think so jajajaj